# KIVY python: ScreenManager

Tags: screen, kivy

What's wrong with this code ? (it displays an empty screen)
I would like to have 2 screens, and on each of them 1 button to simply add a widget (from the python code), and 1 button to switch to the other screen.
When i run the code i can see a blank screen with no button and no label. How to fix all of this ?

PS: It perfectly works when I do the following:

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# ... and

class MyAppli(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor=(1,1,1,1)
        return MyScreenManager()
```

debug.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def initialize(self):   # I know this is not necessary, 
        # but in my real code, i have to proceed like this.

        # ... (some instructions)
        pass

class Menu1(Screen):

    def add_label(self):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Hello", color=(1,0,0,1)))


class Menu2(Screen):

    def add_label(self):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Hello", color=(1,0,0,1)))


Builder.load_file("debug.kv")

class MyAppli(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return MyScreenManager().initialize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

debug.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<MyScreenManager>:
    Menu1:
        id: menu1
    Menu2:
        id: menu2

<Menu1>:
    name: "screen1"

    BoxLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Screen 1"
            color:(1,0,0,1)


        Button:
            text:"Add a label"
            size:(200,50)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.ids.menu1.add_label()

        Button:
            text:"Go to screen 2"
            size:(200,50)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "screen2"


<Menu2>:
    name: "screen2"

    BoxLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Screen 2"
            color:(1,0,0,1)    

        Button:
            text:"Add a label"
            size:(200,50)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.ids.menu2.add_label()

        Button:
            text:"Go to screen 1"
            size:(200,50)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "screen1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do the following in MyScreenManager class. Please refer to the example for details.

## Snippet

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):   # I know this is not necessary,
        # but in my real code, i have to proceed like this.

        # ... (some instructions)
        print("MyScreenManager.initialize called")
...
class MyAppli(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return MyScreenManager()
```

## Example

### debug.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):   # I know this is not necessary,
        # but in my real code, i have to proceed like this.

        # ... (some instructions)
        print("MyScreenManager.initialize called")


class Menu1(Screen):

    def add_label(self):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Hello", color=(1,0,0,1)))


class Menu2(Screen):

    def add_label(self):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Hello", color=(1,0,0,1)))


Builder.load_file("debug.kv")


class MyAppli(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

### debug.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyScreenManager>:
    Menu1:
        id: menu1
    Menu2:
        id: menu2

<Menu1>:
    name: "screen1"

    BoxLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Screen 1"
            color:(1,0,0,1)


        Button:
            text:"Add a label"
            size:(200,50)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.ids.menu1.add_label()

        Button:
            text:"Go to screen 2"
            size:(200,50)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "screen2"


<Menu2>:
    name: "screen2"

    BoxLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Screen 2"
            color:(1,0,0,1)

        Button:
            text:"Add a label"
            size:(200,50)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.ids.menu2.add_label()

        Button:
            text:"Go to screen 1"
            size:(200,50)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "screen1"
```

### Output

[Output Apps Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B44G.png)